# Natural Earth land in GeoServer: line cut through Antarctica for EPSG 900913

Tags: geoserver, mapping, antarctica

I have created a GeoServer layer (GeoServer 2.15) that contains the 10m resolution Natural Earth land countour shapefile data (https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/). But if I preview it in EPSG 900913 (Google Mercator) or create pre-seeded tiles from this layer, the image shows a line that cut right through Antarctica and a color inversion below this line (see picture).
I think it may be related to this problem: https://www.geo-solutions.it/blog/geoserver-continuous-map-wrapping/, but that seems to be solved in recent GeoServer versions.
Anyone who has experienced similar problems and/or knows a solution to this?

[image]

Comment: don't display maps in Web Mercator above or below 85 degrees, the maths gets funny down there. If this still worries you then delete antarctica

Comment: Do you have the "Advanced projection handling" enabled in the WMS service settings?

Comment: Thanks Ian, but the funny line appears around ~ 70 degrees South. For example: When I let GeoServer convert EPSG 4326 GeoTiff data into Web Mercator, it shows al lot more of Antarctica, without any errors.

Comment: Yes Andrea, Advance Projection Handling it is switched on.

Comment: Seems like it should be a bug report then: add reference to the dataset, style used, and request that makes it happen.